# How to use internal:other merge tool with mercurial largefiles extension

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

When rebasing a revision in mercurial one can choose to resolve any merge conflicts by always choosing the "other" (source) version of a file using:

```
hg rebase -s source_rev -d dest_rev --tool internal:other
```

In this case, the rebase needs no user input.

When one uses the same command on a repository which uses the largefiles extension however, conflicts are presented to the user interactively:

```
rebasing 105:b6be8e15656a "Example revision title"
largefile example/largefile.bin has a merge conflict
ancestor was df821d19072c6afc4dce68dadfabea9a11bd0384
keep (l)ocal 01bf634a9dbcdafd400830be8f98477b5410ab6c or
take (o)ther 9adb01d479a1edcc5c9bf6e42249ab5167cdfa1d?
```

Is there any way of always answering "o"? I tried `echo o | hg rebase ...` but this counter-intuitively always chooses "l".

Comment: This sounds like a bug.

Comment: Curious if you filed a bug report at https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/enter_bug.cgi and what happened?

Comment: @DaveInCaz No I did not yet. I had a look in the source code and found that the largefiles extension does indeed not honour the `--tool` option: The entire logic is missing. From what I remember it would be fairly straightforward to copy the necessary code over from the usual merge function, but I never got 'round to actually doing it. If you need, I can probably point you to the right part in the code if you wanted to have a go at it yourself.